# Error importing table to SQL Server from MS Access mdb using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, import, data-migration

I have a Notes table, which is failing to import all the records, giving me these errors:

- Copying to [dbo].[Notes] (Error)
  Messages
  Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification.".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with Destination - Notes.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[Action_DateTime] on Destination - Notes.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Notes.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Notes.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Notes" (34) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (47). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - Notes returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I'm expert with MS Access but new to SQL Server and don't understand what it is telling me.

Please help!

Comment: SSIS is very verbose. The only thing that matters is: _Notes.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[Action_DateTime]  Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type_. Whatever value you have in this column in the source is too big or small or invalid to fit into the target column. You need to inspect that column in the source for weird values that don't look like valid dates or look like weird dates (like 29th Feb). Are both source and target columns `date` types?

Comment: Yes, or at least they should be.  Thanks for the tip, I'll check out the data.

Comment: It turns out there were a couple of invalid dates in the source table.  Thanks.  How do I credit you with the answer?

Comment: The absolute best thing for you to do is write the answer yourself with some detail then you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick pointed out, some data in the Action_DateTime field was invalid for conversion.  Once the data was cleaned up, it imported without issue.  Does make one wonder why that data wasn't invalid for Access.

Many thanks